# Trying to loop through a pandas dataframe and display specific values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pygame

So I'm trying to code a stroop task by looping through a preexisting .csv file. To do this I read the stimuli.csv file into a dataframe.

The .csv file is organized like this:

```
  Colours   Congruent   Word
0   red       0        blue
1   red       1        red
2   red       0        green
3   blue      1        blue
```

I then try to loop through the dataframe checking values in the 'Colours' column and 'Words' column. Colours should be displayed as the font of the word so I check the indexed value in the Colour column to properly display the corresponding colour font. The word displayed itself should be the value indexed in the 'Word' column. I'm getting:

Keyerror: 0

I've looked online but no specific examples help me. Can anyone tell me if i'm going about this all wrong?

```
import pygame
import sys
import psychopy
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd 
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 500))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
myfont= pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 30) 
blue= (0,0,255)
green= (0,255,0)
red= (255,0,0)
while 1: 
    file= r'stimuli.csv'
    df= pd.read_csv('%s' %file, delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
    word= df['Word']                
    congruent= df['Congruent']
    colour= df['Colours']
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        word= df[index].iloc['Word']                
        congruent= df[index].iloc['Congruent']
        colour= df[index].iloc['Colours']
        if df.iloc[index].iloc['Colours']== 'red':
            stim= myfont.render('%s' %word, 1, (255,0,0))
            screen.blit(stim, (300,300))
            pygame.display.flip()
        if df.iloc[index].iloc['Colours']== 'green':
            stim= myfont.render('%s' %word, 1, (0,255,0))
            screen.blit(stim, (300,300))
            pygame.display.flip()
        if df.iloc[index].iloc['Colours']== 'blue':
            stim= myfont.render('%s' %word, 1, (0,0,255))
            screen.blit(stim, (300,300))
            pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key== pygame.K_ESCAPE: 
                msg2= myfont.render("Exiting now", 1, (0, 255, 0))
                screen.blit(msg2, (300, 300))
                pygame.display.flip()

                pygame.display.quit()   
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `df[index].iloc['Colours']` is wrong + the two rows above, try `colour= df.loc[index,'Colours']`

Comment: don't do it in `while True` - now you read file and generate all data  hundreds times in one second. And don't use `flip()` after every change - do it only once in all loop. BTW: pandas as default uses matplotlib - i think you could do it with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example to minify your code. Use it to update your code and make things more readable.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Colours=['Red','Blue']))

d_colour = dict(Red=(255,0,0),Green=(0,255,0),Blue=(0,0,255))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    colour= df.loc[index,'Colours']
    colour_code = d_colour.get(colour)
    print(colour_code)
    #stim= myfont.render('%s' %word, 1, colour_code)
    #screen.blit(stim, (300,300))
    #pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: interesting. So I could potentially do the same thing with Word too right?

Comment: It needs to come from the csv file though, you're just creating a dataframe from a dictionary you're creating

Comment: @wutevs00 yes I know. I do that so you can try the code here. When you post questions on SO it is recommendable to always post data you can verify.